# how to rewrite multiple get variables using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a page with search form(fields: make,model,year,mileage,price)
on form submit url is:

```
http://www.example.com/buy-car.php?make=xxx&model=xxx&mileage=100;10000&year=2000;2015&price=20000;60000&sort=date;DESC
```

i want to rewrite to look like:

```
http://www.example.com/buy-car/xxx/xxx/100;10000/2000;2015/20000;60000/date;DESC
```

Note: query string may or may not contain all the variable

i tried multiple rules but still not getting what i want

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?make=([^\s&]+)&model=([^\s&]+)&year=([^\s&]+)\&mileage=([^\s&]+)\&price=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\^;a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\^;a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\^;0-9-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&mileage=$4&price=$5 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?make=([^\s&]+)&model=([^\s&]+)&year=([^\s&]+)\&mileage=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\^;a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([\^;a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3&mileage=$4 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?make=([^\s&]+)&model=([^\s&]+)&year=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\^;a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1&model=$2&year=$3 [L,QSA,NC]



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?make=([^\s&]+)&model=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1&model=$2 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?year=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\^;0-9-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?year=$1 [L,QSA,NC]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy-car\.php\?make=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy-car/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^buy-car/([\w-]+)/?$ buy-car.php?make=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

what could be the solution.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than maintaining so many rules like that and possibly more due to optional query parameters I strongly suggest using front controller .htaccess like this:

```
DirectryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then use `$_GET['uri']` in the php code to get requested URI and process them.